# unique preceding namespace characters for JS variables to handle scope

Tags: javascript

In different languages, you can have different characters in the variable names, and they also limit what can be the first character vs other characters as being legal.

In JS, what are these characters that are NOT used by other libraries? so that You can safely name a variable and nested ones that link to the global variable as you go down the rabbit hole in scope.

I am currently using underscore.js, so preceding a variable with `_` can/could be problematic.     Same goes with JQuery, and using `$`.    I am getting errors if I try a ruby identifier such as `@` or `~`, and I dont want to use `.` or `#` to avoid confusion with CSS selectors.

What do you know of (or suggest) to precede the variable names with to avoid confusion and overloading.

I would love a/several unique "golden" character(s), but realize this may be dependent on the stacks of libraries the project is using, so for this current project I am using: require, d3, jquery, underscore, backbone, text, dispatch.

sample code:

```
// for each measure in measuresCollection
  _.each(this.measuresCollection.models, function(measure, index) {
    var `this = this;
    for (i=0; i<length; i++){
        // ... some code with new preceding variable name `this
    }
```

Comment: If you're really having problems you could scope all your variables.   var ls = {}; ls.myVar = "A"; ls.myVar2 = 2;  Then you just need to pick one variable that doesn't overlap

Comment: Isn't this more of a namespacing issue than an overloading issue?

Comment: I may have the terms mixed up, but I guess it is better said that the namespace is being overloaded?

Comment: you can use almost any unicode chars: var ƒ=this; but _ and $ are the only non-wordy ascii chars allowed.

Comment: `var ƒthis = this;`   smiling because of `ƒthis`